# Best code practice for javascript if-then-else

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I'm looking for javascript and jquery experts to set me on the right path. I have the following code and I noticed that before the functions are completed the code passes through the focus() and return false; and again once the function comes back false;  Will someone show me the proper way to write this code. Thanks!

```
// validate passwords
if(!VerifyPassword($("#CurrentPassword").val())) {
    $("#CurrentPassword").focus();
    return false;
}
if($("#NewPassword").val() != "") { 
    if(!ValidatePassword($("#NewPassword").val())) {
        $("#NewPassword").focus();
        return false;
    }
    if($("#NewPassword").val() != $("#RetypePassword").val()) {
        alert("The new password is not the same as the retyped password");
        return false;
    }
}

function ValidatePassword(password) {

    if(password.length < 6) { 
        alert("Password must contain at least six characters!"); 
        return false; 
    } 

    re = /[0-9]/; 
    if(!re.test(password)) { 
        alert("Password must contain at least one number (0-9)!"); 
        return false; 
    } 

    re = /[a-z]/; 
    if(!re.test(password)) { 
        alert("Password must contain at least one lowercase letter (a-z)!"); 
        return false; 
    } 

    re = /[A-Z]/; 
    if(!re.test(password)) { 
        alert("Password must contain at least one uppercase letter (A-Z)!"); 
        return false; 
    }

    return true;
}

function VerifyPassword(password) {

    urlString = "../sql/db_verify_password.php?Password=" + password;

    /* send calendar updated information and return status message */
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:  urlString,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('Results').each(function() {
                var status = $(this).find('Status').text();

                if(status != "OK") { 
                    alert(status);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        } 
    });
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting, and what is actually happening? It's not clear exactly what your issue is.

Comment: What do you mean by 'passes thru the focus()'?

Comment: .focus() is used for binding functions to the focus event. Based on your code, it does not look like you are trying to do that, are you trying to set focus?

Comment: What is triggering the execution of this code? An `onclick` event?

Comment: Probably has to do with your asynchronous call.

Comment: I know this is a dumb thing to do but I put an alert("Hi") within the if statement and the alert popped up before the function returned a false condition then the alert popped up again. I know just enough jquery and javascript to be dangerous and I was wondering if there is a better way to structure these statements through chaining so the the alert pops up only after a false condition.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to set the focus to the textbox that has a bad password.

Comment: @PatrickQ yes, it's being triggered by a button on the form

Comment: @PlatinumAzure I'm not sure if you saw this response so I'm reposting it. I know this is a dumb thing to do but I put an alert("Hi") within the if statement and the alert popped up before the function returned a false condition then the alert popped up again. I know just enough jquery and javascript to be dangerous and I was wondering if there is a better way to structure these statements through chaining so the the alert pops up only after a false condition

Answer (score 0):

Let's see what happens in your code!

You first call

```
VerifyPassword($("#CurrentPassword").val())
```

which leads to

```
$.ajax({
    //content omitted
});
```

Now, the first `a` in ajax stands for *asynchronous*. This means a request for some other resource will be made, but you won't wait until the request is finished (if you wait you would call it *synchronous*).
Instead, your code execution continues, setting the focus on the input and returning false.
Finally, when the request finishes and returns, then the function you specified in `success:` will be executed!

Knowing this you want to change the focus within the function specified in `success:`:

Comment: You sparked an idea. I added the "async: false" parameter to my ajax and that solved it.

Comment: @Ernest Bear in mind that this will **block the ui-thread** for the whole time of the request. The user won't be able to interact with the page until the request finishes. This can be very disturbing! (This is why i didn't mentioned this way in my answer)

Comment: I understand. Since this is a single form on the page they won't be interacting with anything else at the time. Thanks for your help. I haven't used StackOverflow much, do I check your answer as having accepted it?

Comment: @Ernest As a general rule: always accept the answer that a) solved your problem and/or b) helped you the most, in case of more than one answer. If this answer is, in your oppinion, useful or otherwise good (good explanatio and so on), then upvote it, too. There may be cases when no answer actually answers the question, then I wouldn't accept one.